# What is meaning of super(ClassName,self).__init__() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Here is the screenshot of our code]

Here is the screenshot of our code

Comment: It's call for constructor of parent class *(`webdriver.Chrome` in your code)*. Docs: [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

Comment: Which part are you asking about? Prior to Python 3, you *had* to specify the two arguments; Python 3 added some infrastructure for supplying the sensible defaults, which is why in Python 3 you virtually always just see `super().__init__()`.

Comment: Also, do not post screenshots of code; enter it as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This a constructor for `webdriver.Chrome`
Please go and see in your webdriver.Chrome class we have constructor called `__init__(self)` magic method,
Now whenever you create an object for the `Booking Class` it will automatically invoke the child class constructor and parent class constructor
Note: Here `super` is a keyword for the invoking parent class constructor
So that's why you're using super(Booking, self).**init**()